# Google Analytics - Referral Sources

Tags: web, google-analytics

I have created my website, let say it is: xyz.com. On this page I have a lot of links to other websites.

links are in form: `<a href="/redirect/?target=https://www.otherwebsite.com" target="_blank">`

on redirect page I am adding information about click to my database and them with php and `header("Refresh:1; URL=https://www.otherwebsite.com");` open desired website.

Is there anything I have to add to a link, or to a website (as i.e. `<meta name="referrer" content="origin">` ) or any other thing I have to do to make sure that owner of the https://www.otherwebsite.com will se in google analytics that someone came from my website?

I was looking for an answer to my question, but unfortunately I have not found a clear answer anywhere, and I do not know exactly how to name such a mechanism.

Thanks!

Comment: As the redirect would still be using your hostname, I believe this should show as a referral. But it's something you can test with Tag Assistant - create a test link, visit that page through the redirect link and inspect the referrer.